# qtip2 on click is only showing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm trying to configure qTip2 to show up when i click a div.

It works only at the first click...

I have a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/8qLXF/1/

The crazy thing is: I'm using the same configuration in other part of my project and it works fine.

Comment: Why is it inside a click event?

Comment: Because I need to get single content to each qtip.
The content will be load with ajax, based on some contents and class inside my div element.

Comment: Putting it there will register the plugin to the element again and again, like whenever the user clicks to the element.

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah, you are right. It works without the click event. What can I do, since I need to get the content when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the plugin to the element every time that element(`a`) is clicked. 
You should do `$('...').qtip({..})` to an element only once.

You can use `.one()` to bind a click event that will happen only once. [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8qLXF/3/)